# Background color in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I have updated the design of my magento store and set the background color to grey. When I go to the front end now, I see the grey background. However actually the background is only grey for the part that is initially shown on the screen. When I scroll it is visible that the lower page has a white background. I have tried this on different size screens and every time the same issue happens: The background if the initial shown part is grey, the rest is white (when scrolled down). What am I doing wrong? I have set the color in the skin.css - did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are setting the background color on the wrong `tag`, `class` or `id` (i.e. your selector) in the CSS. Given that this can be done many ways and still be considered correct, the easiest way to do what you want is to use your browser's developer console to test the changes until you get the result you are looking for.

**Tl;dr**

You probably want to set the color on the `body` tag.